# Infinity axioms with one function symbol

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, infinity, axioms

Let an *Infinity Axiom* be any first-order sentence $\varphi$ such that for any model $M$, if $M \models \varphi$, then the universe of $M$ has to be infinite.

An example of such a sentence is a $\forall\exists$-formula over the signature consisting of one unary function symbol, say $f$, asserting that $f$ is a non-surjective injection.

It is well-known that in a functional language consisting of one unary function symbol, say $S$, and one constant (i.e. $0$-ary function symbol), say $z$, there is a $\forall$-formula (i.e., a purely universal one) that is an Infinity Axiom, according to the definition above.

Question: if we restrict ourselves to a signature that consists only of one (unary, or binary, whatever), function symbol, does there exist a purely universal formula that is an Infinity Axiom? If not, how can one prove it?

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate - a complete answer is given in the paper by Ash linked to in the answer to the duplicate question. In short: there is no universa infinity axiom in a language with a single unary function symbol. But there is one as soon as you have a binary function symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the paper by Ash.